# Is our Beta label being removed?

Tags: discussion, public-beta, graduation

Since we learned that [Matter Modeling is graduating](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/298/5) and [Quantum Computing is graduating](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/517/2293), I'm curious if Space will be too?

Comment: Apparently QuantumComputing has already graduated. MatterModeling??? Our site has been around a lot longer, has 7x visitors per day compared to MatterModeling, has 9x the number of active users, and has roughly the same ratio of answered questions (90% vs 88% here). I don't get it.

Comment: Yes, as of 12/16/2021. Details are here: https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2876/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble Worth noting we had not yet been informed of the graduation of the site at the time this question was asked.

Answer (score 5):

If graduation is to occur, the CMs would announce it here on meta. So just hang in there, and keep making good contributions!

Comment: The CMs will announce this publicly in mid-December, but as far as I can tell they're telling mods in their mod chatrooms, and letting moderators make the announcements.

Answer (score 2):

Unlikely, from my reading of the Area 52 stats. We've got a low questions/day rate, and we still are feeling the curse of "right-answer syndrome", in which typically the first poweruser to provide an excellent and sole answer is the only answer which is ever provided. While that's gotten better, our answers/question ratio is still solidly <2.

Comment: This is in part because second answerers get hammered *hard*, if their answer contradicts the first, *or* agrees with it. the first because they disagree, the second because they are stealing answer.

Comment: wait, answer/question ratio < 2 is suboptimal? What's "the right" ratio then?

Comment: @uhoh Per [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration), 2.5 answers per question or higher is the "right" ratio. This includes questions that go unanswered, which drag the A/Q ratio down. Per Area51, the place where the site lags the most is questions per day. We're at 4.3; they want 10 or more. Per StackExchange, the place where the site lags the most is traffic.

Comment: Regarding the answers/question ratio, when OrganicMarble chimes in with an answer about a Space Shuttle question, that is the answer to the question. The same happens in Astronomy: When ProfRob answers a question, that is the answer to the question. A question that gets one singularly excellent answer -- there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: It's partially just the nature of the beast. Less-than-obviously, we're in large a focused historiography SE. Historiography questions tend to have one right answer, and that reflects what actually happened and the limits of what has been recorded. Between that and the site culture of writing massive aggregate megaanswers (e.g. if somebody asks what smallsat launch companies there are, I would expect to see one answer with a comprehensive list instead of a handful answers each offering a different company), there seems to be few questions with a lot of competing answers