# Graduation of Space Exploration

Tags: discussion, graduation

The Space Exploration Stack Exchange site is scheduled to graduate from Beta to a full site today, December 16th.

The moderator team would like to congratulate our entire user base for the contributions that made this graduation possible. The hard work and diligence in asking and answering questions thoroughly and respectfully has helped get us here. Specifically, graduation criteria has been based on the longevity of our site, the number of open questions, and the number of open questions that have at least one upvoted answer.

Anyone will have the option to self-nominate for new moderator elections, which may take place possibly as far out as 2023. Site customization, such as custom background and badge design isn't immediately planned but may be available in the future.

It has been very rewarding serving as pro tem mod, and I greatly look forward to the future of Space Exploration!

The corresponding META announcement is here: [Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/303080)

Again, Congratulations!!

Comment: Woohoo! But also, what does this mean for a user?

Comment: How will we tell that it has changed?  The Beta icon goes away?  What time does the change happen?

Comment: @geoffc Not sure what time. Some point today. Yes, the immediate change will be the beta logo disappears.

Comment: @BrendanLuke15 Aside from the beta logo being dropped and future (as of yet unscheduled) elections, I don't know much. There will probably be more details in the Meta SE announcement.

Comment: And you got a quote in the announcement! Nice. Congrats!

Comment: [Space SE has graduated, now what? What kinds of changes can we expect in the next year or two?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2879/12102)

Comment: Well, look at that. I thought it would just be in beta forever.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I remember when this site was a rejected proposal on Area 51, and now here it is, all grown up:-) Congrats everyone!

Answer (score 13):

3000 days in beta really does fly by in an instant!

Comment: I remember when it was just a little site, so chubby and cute... Now so cutthroat.  Ah the good old days.

Comment: I've discovered that this is one of the friendlier stack sites. You should try posting at SO...