# Space SE has graduated, now what? What kinds of changes can we expect in the next year or two?

Tags: discussion, graduation

The [Graduation of Space Exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2876/12102) may lead to some changes in this site in the following year or two, small and large, in "look and feel" and in the way it runs.

What are the kinds of changes we can expect to see over the next year or two?

Do changes to other similarly low question rate sites that have happened post graduation offer any insight?

Comment: see for example [We are no longer in beta! (Brace yourself!)](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6106/16047) in Politics SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see the corresponding [Meta SE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/303080) for what kind of changes to expect. Nothing unique to Space Exploration is expected at this time.

Here's a snippet of what is mentioned over there:

> **What does it mean to lose the Beta label?**

> Similar to when we did this two years ago, sites that were eligible and opted to leave Beta will:

> - have the word “Beta” removed from the banner at the top of the site
> - be moved to the “Launched” sites list on Area 51 - which will also remove the A51 info box from the right sidebar of the site
> - retain the artificially-lowered reputation thresholds for site privileges, so that those thresholds stay the same as in Beta
> - have their full-site moderator elections scheduled in the future (more on that in the next section)
>   be eligible for community ads in 2022 (we'll be talking about that more in the new year)

> In the past, we were able to offer a custom site design to graduated sites. Although site redesigns aren’t happening right now, we have a shared interest internally in experimenting with ways to get this or similar benefits back. We know the sites that lost their “Beta” label in 2019 are still waiting for a redesign, too. We hope that some sort of design love (or perhaps theme customization) will come in the future, but we don't have concrete details of what this will look like or a timeline of when this will happen.